# Python print faster on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, cmd, printing

I am working on a program that needs to print to the console very fast.

Right now I'm just printing like this

```
print("X", end="")
```

However, it seems like the windows command line is very slow. Is there a way to speed it up? Or could you recommend a different command line that supports ANSI, different font sizes and can print as fast as I need (~4056 lines of up to 317 characters per line per second)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using flush on every `print`? What is the meaning of putting ~4056 lines per second on the console? How will this be used?

Comment: @lit I'm not really sure why I have flush in there to be honest. I need to print about that many lines per second in order to play videos in the command line (just a weird project I'm working on, got it working for images so far).

Comment: Have you tried updating the entire screen per call via `sys.stdout.buffer.write(screen_buffer)`, where the screen buffer is a `bytearray` that you modify in place?

Comment: @eryksun I haven't, but that sounds interesting. How exactly does that work? Can you give an example of how you'd print a full vertical but half horizontal page of say 1s, then 2s, then 3s using this method?

Comment: Hey, I'm actually making a curses-based terminal image viewer in python for fun right now. So... how did it go? Do you have anything to share? Not necessarily source code, just something to get inspired by. Also MAN it's hard to reach you, this comment section is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare two different concepts of printing (characters versus lines, see explanation in bold below) as indicated in the following `.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
if "%~1"=="" (
    set "_flush= "
) else (
    set "_flush=, flush=True"
)
set "_line=317"
:loop
if not "%time:~-2%"=="00" goto :loop
set "_t0=%time%"
python -c "for num in range(0,4096*%_line%): print('X', end=''%_flush%);"
set "_t1=%time%"
python -c "for num in range(0,4096): print('X'*%_line%, end=''%_flush%);"
set "_t2=%time%"
cls
echo %~f0 %* 
set _
```

Result shows that

- printing **characters one by one** takes approximately 7 seconds (`_t1 - _t0`)
- printing **the same data in sequence of pre-prepared lines** takes approximately half a second (`_t2 - _t1`) :

```
D:\bat\SO\53659583.bat
_flush=
_line=317
_t0=23:55:03,00
_t1=23:55:09,96
_t2=23:55:10,47
```

Comment: Thanks. This is something I just thought of trying, and I implemented it and it improved the speed by about 20%. I suspect that a decent amount of the runtime may actually be due to rendering the images on the fly, and so I'm going to work on doing that beforehand and see how it goes from there.

Comment: Also tried printing each image as one by adding each line separated by "\n" to a large string, but now it randomly prints a few �� in each image. Not sure why exactly.

Comment: `�` is just a _Replacement Character_ (Unicode `U+FFFD`). Appears if  the open command window **font** does not contain a character. Try e.g. _Dejavu Sans Mono_.